# Elastic Search for mobile internal memory search(8gb, 16gb, etc)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

My elasticsearch db has a product index has a field

```
internal_memory : 8gb
```

I need this field to be returned for following sample strings:

```
8 gb
 8 gb
8gb
16 gb (will have less score obviously)
16gb (will have less score obviously)
```

How can I write a custom analyser for this?

Should we use nGrams for such searches as this is not a autocomplete or per key stroke search?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html

You need to use group>0 (so, the separator is also one of the tokens) and specify regex for digits and whitespaces as separators like this '(\d+|\s+)'. Unfortunately, spaces will be also counted as tokens, you may need to filter them out with token filter.

Comment: can i use Word Delimiter Token Filter?